# Is there any way that automate the localizations translations of my app's .arb file

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, ln

I have an `app_en.arb` file which contains my localization translation for the English language.

I want to generate other languages's localization files based on this one, and I want to know if there are some software/services that might accelerate this process such as auto-translation, listing those translations for editing them...

Thanks.

Comment: seeking recommendations :p

Comment: Give it a try https://pub.dev/packages/auto_translator

Comment: Try [Crowdin](http://crowdin.com/) - it's a cloud-based solution that can handle these tasks and a lot more. There is a Free plan even. Also, Crowdin is free for Open-Source projects.

Answer (score 0):

Found this package, haven't tried it yet:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_arb_translator

> A command line tool which simplifies translation of Flutter ARB files.
> You can simply choose a service from supported list: Azure Cognitive
> Services, Yandex, Google Cloud, DeepL and flexibly adjust translation
> options.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using ChatGPT with GPT-4.

Tried uploading the file first, didn't work well, so ended up just copying everything into the prompt and it was great!

My initial prompt to start it all was `Do you know what an app_en.arb file is?`

It did, and I followed by requesting a translation to the desired language and copy-pasting everything into the prompt